# Difference in Generics Declaration

Tags: typescript

In typescript, is there a difference between

```
a : T<x> | T<y>
```

and

```
a : T<x | y>
```

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: @ritaj see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends entirely on the definition of `T`, which is not included here.  Since the code doesn't seem to be a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can only speak in generalities.

When you say that `T<X | Y>` is equivalent to `T<X> | T<Y>` for all `X` and `Y`, you are saying that `T<X>` [distributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) over unions in its type parameter.  In general, `T<X>` does *not* distribute over its type parameter.  This *can* happen, but it usually doesn't.

In order to explore some cases, let's introduce some testing equipment:

```
type Compare<U, V> = [U] extends [V]
  ? ([V] extends [U] ? "mutually assignable" : "subtype")
  : [V] extends [U] ? "supertype" : "unrelated";
```

The `Compare<U, V>` type will compare types `U` and `V` to see if `U` is assignable to `V` and/or vice versa.  If `T<X | Y>` is the same as `T<X> | T<Y>`, then `Compare<T<X | Y>, T<X> | T<Y>>` should return `"mutually assignable"`.  If not, then you will get one of the other three possibilities: either `T<X | Y>` is a *supertype* of `T<X> | T<Y>` (that is, `T<X> | T<Y>` is assignable to `T<X | Y>`), or `T<X | Y>` is a *subtype* of `T<X> | T<Y>` (that is, `T<X | Y>` is assignable to `T<X> | T<Y>`), or `T<X | Y>` is *unrelated* to `T<X> | T<Y>` (that is, neither type is assignable to the other).

```
type X = { a: string; b: number } | number;
type Y = { c: boolean; d: any[] } | string;
```

I've got some *particular* example for `X` and `Y` here, so in the following tests if `T<X | Y>` is declared equivalent to `T<X> | T<Y>`, it's just *evidence* that it's true for general `X` and `Y`, and not *proof*.  Obviously if I pick `X` and `Y` to be the same type, then `T<X | Y>` will always equal `T<X> | T<Y>`.  So I've just chosen a sufficiently distinct `X` and `Y` to be illustrative.

Okay, let's get started:

---

Here are some generic types which *are* distributive over unions in their type parameter, where `T<X> | T<Y>` is equivalent to `T<X | Y>`:

• Constant type functions that don't consult their type parameter are distributive:

```
type Constant<T> = string;
type ConstantDistributes = Compare<Constant<X | Y>, Constant<X> | Constant<Y>>;
// mutually assignable
```

• The identity type function is distributive:

```
type Identity<T> = T;
type IdentityDistributes = Compare<Identity<X | Y>, Identity<X> | Identity<Y>>;
// mutually assignable
```

• The union of the type parameter with something is distributive:

```
type OrSomething<T> = T | { z: string };
type OrSomethingDistributes = Compare<
  OrSomething<X | Y>,
  OrSomething<X> | OrSomething<Y>
>; // mutually assignable
```

• The intersection of the type parameter with something is distributive:

```
type AndSomething<T> = T & { z: string };
type AndSomethingDistributes = Compare<
  AndSomething<X | Y>,
  AndSomething<X> | AndSomething<Y>
>; // mutually assignable
```

• A [conditional type in which the checked type is the "naked" type parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) (so just `T extends ...` instead of `SomeFunctionOf<T> extends ...`) is distributive:

```
type NakedConditional<T> = T extends object ? { x: T } : { y: T };
type NakedConditionalDistributes = Compare<
  NakedConditional<X | Y>,
  NakedConditional<X> | NakedConditional<Y>
>; // mutually assignable
```

• A generic type which is [bivariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in its type parameter is distributive.  This is quite uncommon, since bivariant types are generally unsound.  Method parameters in TypeScript are [treated as bivariant](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant).  Function parameters in general are treated as bivariant if you turn off [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types)... but you shouldn't turn that off.

```
interface Bivariant<T> {
  method(x: T): void;
}
type BivariantDistributes = Compare<
  Bivariant<X | Y>,
  Bivariant<X> | Bivariant<Y>
>;
// mutually assignable
```

---

Those cases were chosen specifically to make the equivalence hold.  Now for the more common cases, where they are *not* equivalent:

• A generic type which is [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in its type parameter will *not* distribute.  In such types, `T<X | Y>` will be a *supertype* of `T<X> | T<Y>`:

```
interface Covariant<T> {
  prop: T;
}
type CovariantIsASupertype = Compare<
  Covariant<X | Y>,
  Covariant<X> | Covariant<Y>
>;
// supertype
```

• A generic type which is [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in its type parameter will *not* distribute.  In such types, `T<X | Y>` will be a *subtype* of `T<X> | T<Y>`:

```
interface Contravariant<T> {
  (arg: T): void;
}
type ContravariantIsASubtype = Compare<
  Contravariant<X | Y>,
  Contravariant<X> | Contravariant<Y>
>;
// subtype
```

• A generic type which is [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in its type parameter will *not* distribute.  In such types, `T<X | Y>` will be *unrelated to* of `T<X> | T<Y>`:

```
interface Invariant<T> {
  (arg: T): T;
}
type InvariantIsUnrelated = Compare<
  Invariant<X | Y>,
  Invariant<X> | Invariant<Y>
>;
// unrelated
```

---

Let's recap.  Without knowing anything about `T`, you cannot count on `T<X | Y>` being equivalent to `T<X> | T<Y>` for all `X` and `Y`.  There are some specific cases of `T` where it is known to distribute over unions, and in those cases there is no difference.  Usually, though, there is a difference.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAQwE4QDwFUA0UBqAfFALxQDaWAulBAB7AQB2AJgM4X5UBQUUA-FAAU5LrQbN2FagKgAiBAFdgi5ABs1IKMjZsAlgHMmyAEZqIcqAC55bRSdCQ5ASl7XONeo1YdKNQXJ2kKiOFu5yikzoasiMLHIA3NzcoVAAGqRQAN7aNmzAqHpMBglQJjZMiggmEKhQAL5QAD5QldW1SakAmpk5AMY2JnBw5shMpSw2YyDkNI0t+YXFSdwA9KtQACIAkgDKACoAStsAQlj72-gAosmp8Ez5Y8AY+8Rki0UlKeDQ949MwE2eg+JmUEA4ZHgSDQmD+wCeGAyLS6hDwcIRaWILXRAIwKMISXWUCUKnUmm0ukMxjMEFuPyg2xYzGAelALzeUH2nXpjOZrJAQJBYIhsEQKHQGF5AP5iOaUBReClLLZmLlSpl+MJGxJqg0Wh0+iMpnMdMgUAA8qhdogIMAABafdmZfZynIALzyBU+DW5Zst1oQtodxUFXtBjBFUPFmDc-pt9sdSPlqNjVvjwYMiKxFrTgYTxTxhG4BKgRJ1ZP1lKNNNN0AAgqwA0HHa9nVAAGTZKAeqAfYo+75mhssJv5gyhwrh8GZKMwjBuYejjOy5EpviL9OJ7MbvPLlHF0pl5S68kGqnG2mD6AAOWQAGsICx7ixWXo4MY1E6yC6vJIOHATAAKwgPpgFkHI6BsF1GhsHIQCggdUlvB8n3fF8WXfdQJz0KdIzFOc3GQx9n1fTDPyTBVCPvYi0NIj8szlIjUNYOj1ELA9S21Y8KwpQ1qRNbgikYVAADNkD6aATj0AA3NA9ARVssjcXc4BYIRIM5ZwbGkuA9BYJJ6ivKApNkwonmw3CZ3wiU3BMuSMTlSi+DsszcVVFoXPk3F9wJNYuNJPVePPGs-Kga9zRdHYDmOM4LmuZIhNqMSJNFUyvOeRS3DAVA4DAKCDKM+A0qebY2DrXZFGCVJIWsmM+CK+y3MctdUsa553Na1znh8rVe0q2pQgSgEkvE353wKZBitxTK+CENADCgrSoB0vSCrucbUEmtrSvK+xqtFaEbPqjatq6ldkxwNx7gmqb2uza7Ntu9jfKJOwHB+IbhOS6BtiYJ6ZuEebFvy7hDNSX7btKrAoggGI4isw66oZP62vOpzkaejqIdRnrQsiaJYkfbggA)

Comment: Well I'll need to set some time aside to go through all of it but that's just my lack of knowledge of the subject. This is one of the most thorough answers I got on SO, thank you so much!! :D Very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

They are **not** the same.

`a: T<x> | T<y>` means that `a` is of **either** of type `T<x>` or of `T<y>`.

`a: T<x | y>` means that `a` is of type `T` where `T` is generic over the type `x | y`.

---

Any value of type `T<x> | T<y>` is assignable to any variable of type `T<x | y>`, **but not the other way around**.

I made a [quick demonstration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20X%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20foo%3A%20X%3Cnumber%20%7C%20boolean%3E%3B%0D%0Avar%20bar%3A%20X%3Cnumber%3E%20%7C%20X%3Cboolean%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo%20%3D%20bar%3B%0D%0Abar%20%3D%20foo%3B%0D%0A) showcasing this.

Comment: `Any value of type T<x> | T<y> is assignable to any variable of type T<x | y>, but not the other way around.` False, if they are assignable depends on weather the type parameter is in a co-variant  contra-variant or bi-variant position.